# Remotely install WS2012 R2?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-home-server

***TL;DR How do I install Windows Sever 2012 over a network to a remote sever?***

I purchased an Acer WHS h340 for very cheap, but it didn't come with the Recovery Disks and had a bad motherboard. Replaced the motherboard with a new h341 motherboard.

Been trying the last the few days to get Windows Server 2012 installed on the box. I have access to Dreamspark, so my copy of WS12 is legit. I downloaded the Windows Home Sever Connector from Microsoft, but that does not find my server.

When I look at my connected clients in my router, I see the WHS has an ip address. However I am unable to PING the host name, or the IP address. In my router, the host name shows up too. However, when I NBTSTAT -A IPADDRESS the host name I get back a 172 address.

So I am at a loss. I am afraid the Windows Home Sever Connector isn't able to see my WHS.

I contacted Acer and they said my box was out of warranty. So they referred me to a 3rd party that handles their boxes now, I asked if I could buy recovery disks and they said no.

Is there a guide on how to install an OS without the recover disks?

Answer (score 0):

Well you are not going to be able to install it over the network if it's not responding. The only other way would be to `pxe` boot it but this system most likely does not support that. I would plug in a USB CD drive and try and try to install it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If it is already out of warranty, is there any reason you couldn't just take the the HDD out and throw it into another box to reinstall?

Also, they seem to have a recovery cd option on their website.

http://store.acer.com/store/aceramer/en_US/eRecovery

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but when I do that method, the hardware drivers aren't loading right. They no longer have those disks. I tried.